# Compiling libidin.a to iOS

Tags: ios, terminal

I want to compile the libidin.a framework to iOS but I ran into a terminal problem during so.

This is the guide i'm using to do that:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/CompilingLibidn

The guide says I should cd to the folder where the libidin.a is at and write the following line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/iphone --host=arm-apple-darwin --disable-shared CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 CFLAGS="-arch armv6 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=2.0 -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk" CPP=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp AR=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar
```

But I get the follwing answer:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Since I have no clue about what i'm doing in terminal, I really need your help.

Thanks

Comment: check for executable flag on configure script

Comment: dont know what that means...

Comment: do ls -al ./configure and place an output here

Comment: ls: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: did you 'cd to the folder where the libidin.a is' ?

Comment: cd - is a terminal command that performs change dir operation to the folder specified as argument. eample: cd ~/myprojects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75110/discussion-between-nimrod-shai-and-heximal).

Comment: @NimrodShai Please learn the very basics of working with the command line. You error is trivial (you need to `cd` into the directory where the configure script resides). Stack Overflow is **not** a beginners' tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found out that I added the precompiled libidin.a file only one of my targets and this is why it failed.